# Subdomain in ActiveModel::Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I use to generate JSON ActiveModel :: Serializer (gem 'active_model_serializers').
I have a subdomain.
There helper for that.

```
module UrlHelper
   def with_subdomain(subdomain)
     subdomain = (subdomain || "")
     subdomain += "." unless subdomain.empty?
     [subdomain, request.domain, request.port_string].join
   end

   def url_for(options = nil)
     if options.kind_of?(Hash) && options.has_key?(:subdomain)
       options[:host] = with_subdomain(options.delete(:subdomain))
     end
     super
   end
end
```

How to return the entire url with subdomain?

```
class TestSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
   attributes :id, :url

   def url
     object.url # get "testurl"
     # root_path(subdomain: object.url) # does not work
   end
end
```

So it returns "testurl" - `http://example.com/testurl`

It is necessary to return `http://testurl.example.com/`

Comment: Please provide your `object.url` method code as well.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean

Comment: I'm sorry, I understood what you wanted myself. Does changing `root_path` to `root_url` help?

Comment: Added this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As found out in comments, `root_path` had to be changed to `root_url`. `_path` helpers doesn't yield host name, so link generated with output from them will lead to current domain/subdomain.